# Creating a SharedObject in red5 (shared swf file)

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, red5

I want to share swf file with Red5 flash server. This swf file is a slideshow for a presentation. A teacher changes a slide and students will see the changes.

I saw a tutorial in youtube for sharedObject in the Red5 but it is not what I needed. I think I should detect clicked Position from a client and send it to others.

How can I detect clicked position of shared object and send it from others ?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do you need to share screen of the teacher with student?

Comment: I need to share a swf file (converted from microsoft powerpoint)

Comment: You can detect the mouse position in flash, but you'll have to add that code to your swf. The shared ball example in red5 shows how to pass position between viewers using a shared object.